# How do I use a Vue single file component in a view with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, yarnpkg

I've tried many approaches and always get some kind of build or runtime error. I'm somewhat surprised I haven't been able to find a working example or post regarding this after much searching.  I created a new project with Typescript using the Vue UI then create the following component:

```
<template>
  <div class="navigation">
    BACK | NEXT buttons go here
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component
export default class BackNext extends Vue {
}
</script>
```

Next, I tried to use this component in a .vue view file and this is about as close as I've gotten:

```
<template>
  <div class="question">
    <h1>Personal</h1>
    <back-next />
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import BackNext from "../../components/BackNext.vue";
@Component
export default class Personal extends Vue {
  components = {
    'back-next': BackNext
  }
}
</script>
```

But this fails with the following build errors:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 11 errors4:22:27 PM

These dependencies were not found:

* core-js/modules/es.object.get-prototype-of in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/getPrototypeOf.js
* core-js/modules/es.object.to-string in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/isNativeReflectConstruct.js, ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/typeof.js
* core-js/modules/es.reflect.construct in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/createSuper.js, ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/isNativeReflectConstruct.js
* core-js/modules/es.regexp.to-string in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/isNativeReflectConstruct.js
* core-js/modules/es.string.iterator in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/typeof.js
* core-js/modules/es.symbol in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/typeof.js
* core-js/modules/es.symbol.description in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/typeof.js
* core-js/modules/es.symbol.iterator in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/typeof.js
* core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator in ./node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/typeof.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save core-js/modules/es.object.get-prototype-of core-js/modules/es.object.to-string core-js/modules/es.reflect.construct core-js/modules/es.regexp.to-string core-js/modules/es.string.iterator core-js/modules/es.symbol core-js/modules/es.symbol.description core-js/modules/es.symbol.iterator core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator
```

It's not clear that a standard new project with Typescript support enabled should need to to go off to install a bunch of dependencies to use some very standard functionality and I don't want to further mess up my project by installing a bunch of things that may or may not be needed.

npm version 6.13.4

node version 12.16.1

yarn version 1.22.4

vue version @vue/clu 4.5.3

Comment: _"a .view file"_  shouldn't that be a `.vue` file?

Comment: Can't see anything like this in their current issues list. Have you tried the trusty old `rm -r node_modules package-lock.json && npm install`?

Comment: I meant .vue view file.  The project is an SPA with the pages in view subdirectory.

Comment: Did you delete `package-lock.json` along with `node_modules` before running `yarn install`?

Comment: Yes, I deleted both and now it seems a pile of @vue dependencies are not being added back when I try npm install.  I found another article suggesting I npm install @vue/cli-service -h which I tried and now it's on to another failure : Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel'

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that Yarn uses `yarn.lock`, not `package-lock.json`. Last time, then I'm out of ideas... `rm -r node_modules yarn.lock && yarn install`. Failing that, try using `npm` instead of `yarn`

Comment: It was the yarn.lock file, after removing and running yarn install npm run serve works.  thanks!

Comment: The classics never die

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register it in the decorator

```js
import BackNext from "../../components/BackNext.vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    BackNext,
  },
})

export default class Personal extends Vue {
  private dataItems = [];

...
```